# Understanding the stack trace in recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, computer-science

I am learning about recursion and how the stack works. I am having trouble understanding the stack trace in this function and why my console.log statements say what they do;

```
function expoRecursion(base, exp) {
  debugger;
  if(exp == 1) {
    console.log('the exp value is ' + exp + ' , base is returned');
    return base;
  } else {
    console.log('line 278 the function evaluates ' + expoRecursion(base, exp -1));
    return base * expoRecursion(base, exp-1);
  }
}
expoRecursion(2,3);
```

I have run this in Chrome dev tools and stepped through it, but can't seem to get the nature of why after the base case is returned when the exp is 1, we pop expoRecursion(2, 2-1), then go to expoRecursion (2, 3-1), and then add back on to the stack expoRecursion(2, 2-1) when that has been evaluated already? Then confusion seems to come from my log statements where they read:

```
the exp value is 1 , base is returned  
line 278 the function evaluates 2  
the exp value is 1 , base is returned  
line 278 the function evaluates 4  
the exp value is 1 , base is returned  
line 278 the function evaluates 2  
the exp value is 1 , base is returned
```

Why is the last statement 2 and then the final returned value comes back as 8?

Comment: You're creating new recursions by calling the `expoRecursion` function to log its results `console.log(..... expoRecursion(base, exp -1));`

Comment: Your log statement and your return statement both invoke the recursion. That's probably not what you want.

Comment: oh crap, I didnt realize I was calling the function agin in the console.log statement.

Answer (score 1):

The others have already pointed out the basis of your confusion: you recurred *twice* in your **else** clause.  I think this will clean it up for you: recur only once, save the result, and use *that* in both places:

```
} else {
    recur_result = expoRecursion(base, exp -1);
    console.log('line 278 the function evaluates ' + recur_result);
    return base * recur_result;
}
```

See whether that matches your expectations.

Comment: Understood, I see my error and what added to my confusion.